# Find_each taking ~30 minutes between batches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I have 2.6 million records I'm trying to generate public IDs for.  It took at most 3-hours locally.

Running the rake task on heroku is taking considerably longer:

```
Episode.where(public_id: nil).find_each do |e|
  Rails.logger.info "updating #{e.id} ..."          
  e.set_public_id
  e.save
end
```

`set_public_id` just generates a code and check that it's not a duplicate:

```
code = generate_code
self.public_id = code
dupe = self.class.where(public_id: self.public_id)
```

Looking at the logger output it seems to complete a batch of 1000 every ~30 minutes.  I did add an index to `:public_id` when I created the column.

What can I do to make this go faster?

Comment: Why are you running the dupe check every time? That is probably taking a ton of extra time. Since I assume this is a job you'll only run once, why don't you forget about checking for duplicates, run it all the way through, then at the very end, check if there were any duplicates and fix it? That'll be much quicker, and chances are you'll only have 1 or 2 duplicates if any.

Comment: Good idea!  The dupe check didn't seem to impact performance locally but this makes sense.

Comment: I use a library called activerecord-import as well, which is for bulk saving. You might want to look into it as well. Activerecord doesn't do bulk saving by default, but activerecord-import adds it. https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

Comment: On Heroku your vm is sharing resources with others, the database instance isn't local, etc. Not surprising there's a difference. Another approach rather than a fixup as @David said is to query once for all the non-null id's and save them in  a `Set` in memory. It's only a few megabytes. Then do the membership test there rather than a separate query once per record. @David's bulk upload idea is excellent, too.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first experience with anything this size so I got away with being lazy I guess.  Could you expound on saving them in a 'Set' in memory?  Unfamiliar with the terminology/process.

Comment: @Ashbury Essentially, you query your DB for all non-null ideas (Episode.where.not(public_id: nil)) and you save them into or something.... I would do Episode.where.not(public_id: nil).pluck(:public_id). That'll give you an array with all the public_ids... which, by assumption of your DB is already unique. Then, I would do something like hash = Hash.new(array_of_public_ids.collect { |v| [v, true] }), so now you'll have a hash with all keys being public_ids, and all values being true. So your dupe test is just hash[public_id] (which is either true or nil)

Comment: Removing the dupe check hasn't noticeably shortened the time.  I'm trying to figure out bulk updating now.

Comment: How did you implement `generate_code`? I just consider could we make a raw query for update or not!

Comment: characters = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('0'..'9').to_a;  code = code = characters.sample(6).join;

Answer (score 3):

I think `find_each` default batch size was too much for heroku.  What finally made it work was reducing the batch size to '100'

```
.find_each(batch_size: 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Deciding the size of the batch in `find_each` is a good decision, as the default batch size is 1000, another thing you can also do is use it in conjunction with `.lazy`, `find_each(batch_size: 100).lazy.each do ...`